# Activity jumps out when open (Android). Any error on code?

Tags: android, runtime-error

Activity closed itself when open. What's the error here? I'm still not very familiar with Android. Someone please help me out, thanks.

```
public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPName);
    String name = nameET.getText().toString();

    EditText ICET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPIC);
    String IC = ICET.getText().toString();

    RadioGroup genderRG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgpCPGender);
    Integer genderID = genderRG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton genderRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(genderID);
    String gender = (String)genderRB.getText();

    EditText emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPEmail);
    String email = emailET.getText().toString();

    EditText addressET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPAddress);
    String address = addressET.getText().toString();

    EditText contactET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPContact);
    String contact = contactET.getText().toString();

    EditText oldPassET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPOldPass);
    String oldPass = oldPassET.getText().toString();

    EditText newPassET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPNewPass);
    String newPass = newPassET.getText().toString();

    EditText confirmPassET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPRetypeNewPass);
    String confirmPass = confirmPassET.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
        setTitle("Edit Profile");
    }

    public void SaveChanges(View view){
        if(name.matches("")) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditProfileActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Please make sure all information are keyed in correctly.");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        } else {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditProfileActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Success");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Profile has been successfully updated.");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    public void ChangePassword(View view){

        if(newPass.matches(confirmPass)) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditProfileActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Success");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Your password has been changed successfully.");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        } else if (oldPass.matches("") || newPass.matches("") || confirmPass.matches("")) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditProfileActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Please key in all the password fields");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding that random text, add some details like your manifest file, how you calling the activity, what's the flow etc.

Comment: Please start from here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but manifest file and calling activity has no problem because i've tested it runs without all the codes i typed.

Comment: Thanks all, i've solved the problem using if else statement for radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you cannot initialize variable outside of onCreate(),and you cannot write findViewById() outside of onCreate or any other parent Method in android,we have write the all initialization statements inside the onCreate() method,
so you can declare the the global variables outside of onCreate() and initialiize them to onCreate(). 
Try This.

```
    EditText nameET, ICET, emailET, addressET, contactET, oldPassET, newPassET, confirmPassET;
    RadioGroup genderRG, genderRB;
    String name, IC, gender, email, address, contact, oldPass, newPass, confirmPass;
    Integer genderID,

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
        setTitle("Edit Profile");

        nameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPName);
        name = nameET.getText().toString();

        ICET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPIC);
        ICET.getText().toString();

        genderRG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgpCPGender);
        genderID = genderRG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        genderRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(genderID);
        gender = (String) genderRB.getText();

        emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPEmail);
        email = emailET.getText().toString();

        addressET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPAddress);
        address = addressET.getText().toString();

        contactET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPContact);
        contact = contactET.getText().toString();

        oldPassET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPOldPass);
        oldPass = oldPassET.getText().toString();

        newPassET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPNewPass);
        newPass = newPassET.getText().toString();

        confirmPassET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCPRetypeNewPass);
        confirmPass = confirmPassET.getText().toString();

    }
```

Comment: if you have not declare this activity in manifest file you must have to declare it  and you are calling any other activity,so you must have to declare that activity too in manifest file.

Comment: I've changed according to the above, but the activity still close itself when open. If i delete all my codes in onCreate, it can be successfully open. So is there any problem of my code? It doesn't shows any red lines in the IDE.

Comment: have you register this activity in manifest file?
and it will be more helpful if you put your error log from logcat.

Answer (score -1):

Add it to your manifest file, it depends on how you call your activity

Comment: You should define all your xml components in onCreate method

Comment: Yes, i've followed the answers above but the activity is still closing. When i delete all my own codes in onCreate, it can be open

Comment: Try your activity context on setting its title, like below:
this.setTitle("My Title");

Comment: Where can i view the crash log? Because it doesn't shows any errors below. It just closed on my phone

Comment: Try my last comment, and your log is in your idea log , when it crashes you'll see the error caused the crash in red

Comment: it does not shows any error. it just exit itself when i try to open the activity. and do you mean setting the title of the activity? i've added it before posting this question. and tried adding "this." in front doesn't help too.

Comment: RadioButton returns boolean, not string, take a look at your components

Comment: but if i change to gender = (RadioButton)genderRB.getText(); , it says Incompatible types. Required: java.lang.String Found: android.widget.RadioButton . I put gender as String above because i want it in text. p/s After that i added .toString() behind it, but still activity closing.

Comment: When i try deleting the whole gender thing away, the activity opens successfully, so i'm sure it's the problem that causes it.

Comment: So we narrow it down right, you should check the radio button by its id, in the snippet here in doc it is completely obvious
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html